# Make PHP-FPM Listen at 'IPAddress:Port' Instead of '/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;'

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi, debian-wheezy

As I was load testing my site today (using [blitz.io](https://www.blitz.io/)); despite lots of RAM (more than 50%) and CPU power (over 70%) available, results showed that my site started timing out at a certain number of concurrent users per second.

Nginx error log for my site (/var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log) showed something like this:

> 2013/02/12 19:03:57 [error] 13749#0: *3175 connect() to
>   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 54.123.456.46,
>   server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"

Googling the error led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10470109/1071413) which states using TCP\IP connection instead of unix socket as the solution to the problem; as unix socket's *"problems on high-load cases is well-known"*.

So, as suggested by the answer:

- I replaced `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` with `listen 127.0.0.1:9000` in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
- As there's no `/etc/nginx/php_location` on my distrio (Debian Wheezy), I did nothing about it.
- Since I use `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;` in the Nginx configuration file for my site, i.e., /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com, I replaced it with `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`

Now the problem is, I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error when I visit my website. Yes, I did `reload` Nginx and PHP-FPM. What am I doing wrong? (A total newbie here, doing my best to learn by doing.)

In case this is relevant, when I do `sudo service php5-fpm restart`, I get this error:

```
[FAIL] Restarting PHP5 FastCGI Process Manager: php5-fpm failed!
```

And this is happening only since I made the aforementioned changes. How can I fix this?

Please let me know if I should get more information.

---

### UPDATE

The file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` says this:

```
#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

#   # With php5-fpm:
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

So, does that mean, if my server is running PHP-FPM, it *SHOULD*, without a choice, use `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`?

Comment: Please paste your entire `www.conf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used `$ sudo php5-fpm -t` command to test if PHP-FPM's settings are fine (if not, it'll show me some error/info).

So, here's what the output looked like:

```
[13-Feb-2013 18:35:00] ERROR: [/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:33] value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY
[13-Feb-2013 18:35:00] ERROR: Unable to include /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf from /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf at line 33
[13-Feb-2013 18:35:00] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
[13-Feb-2013 18:35:00] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

The error says, something's wrong in Line 33 of of `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, which happens to be this: `listen 127.0.0.1:9000` (not so much of a coincidence, is it?).

After seeing it, I immediately compared it with other lines, and then it struck me, an `=` (equal-to sign) is missing!

So, this is what it's supposed to be: `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` and that fixed everything!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like (based on the 502 and the error message) that php-fpm service is failing to start.

Could something else be using port 9000?  To check run:

```
sudo lsof -P | grep TCP | grep LISTEN
```

and look for something like `TCP localhost:9000 (LISTEN)`. If there is, you could just use a different port, say 9001.

Good place to check would be the php-fpm error log.  It may not be enabled by default.  If you look at your php-fpm conf file (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf on my system) you'll find the 'error_log' setting.  This is the path to your error log.  If this is commented out, un-comment it, restart the php-fpm service again and check what the contents of the log file say.

Comment: **(1)** No, port 9000 doesn't seem to be used by any other service. Here's the output of [`$ sudo lsof -P | grep TCP | grep LISTEN`](http://paste.kde.org/670796/) **(2)** here are the contents of PHP-FPM log file at `/var/log/php5-fpm.log` -- http://paste.kde.org/670802/, I still dont understand what to do...?!

Comment: Looks like it's still trying to use the file socket `NOTICE: using inherited socket fd=6, "/var/run/php5-fpm.sock"`. Is there a listen setting in /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf?

Comment: No. But it has this: `include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf` which _probably_ means it includes /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf, in which I did make changes as mentioned in my question.

Comment: I got more information from `sudo php5-fpm -t`: http://paste.kde.org/670826/ -- as shown in the error, line 33 of /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf is this: `listen 127.0.0.1:9000`

Answer (score 3):

You can use IP/port or Unix socket on your choices.

This depends on your php-fpm config, the file is `www.conf`, in my system (Ubuntu 16.04), this file located at `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d`.

Within this file, you can find a directive named `listen`, if you set this directive to `/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`, for example, then in your nginx site config `fastcgi_pass` should be `unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`;

But if you set listen to `127.0.0.1:9000`, then `fastcfg_pass` should be `127.0.0.1:9000`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[13-Feb-2013 18:35:00] ERROR: [/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:33] value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY
[13-Feb-2013 18:35:00] ERROR: Unable to include /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf from /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf at line 33
```

It's not loading `www.conf` because it has an error at line 33, and so is probably falling back to defaults which use a socket.

Comment: The line 33 of www.conf is `listen 127.0.0.1:9000` which I am using instead of `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` as the latter is causing time outs under load (as mentioned in my question).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and changed the IP from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0
and the problem resolved !
the result should look like this:

listen = 0.0.0.0:9000